# How to replace json value in query of ExecteSQL processor in nifi?

Tags: sql, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to replace value in the query that is fetched from another processor in nifi, How can I achieve this or what is the best way to do it?
The processor details are as follows,

1. Execute SQL Processor -> `SELECT Rno FROM sampleDB WHERE operation = 1;`
2. SplitAvro Processor
3. Convert Avro to Json -> Here I get following JSON `{'Rno':'121'}`
4. Execute SQL Processor -> `DELETE FROM NewDB WHERE Rno = X` (here X should be replaced by the Rno received from previous processor that is '121')

How to achieve step 4 what processors should be used in addition to the above ones?

Comment: you can use `PutDatabaseRecord` for step 4

Comment: `PutSQL` by setting `SQL Statement` property to delete query `delete from NewDB where Rno = ${Rno}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @VikramsinhShinde , I should use `EvaluateJsonPath` processor in step 4 and set the json value as flow file attribute. And Step 5 should be `PutSQL` as suggested by you in the comment.

Comment: The error message clearly says that there is a syntax error while forming SQL statement. How are you forming the SQL query for deletion operation?

Comment: Please update question with your flow screenshot